# PAE enabled

Tags: windows

```
SystemProduct Name    ProLiant ML350 G5Processor Package 1 (Socket 1, Core = 4)    Intel Xeon Processor @ 2.50 GhzOperating system environment    Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition, Service Pack 2 (Build 3790)Total memory    8192 MbytesBoard 0DIMM 1A ( DDR2-FBD )    2048 Mbytes (667 MHz)DIMM 2B ( DDR2-FBD )    2048 Mbytes (667 MHz)DIMM 3C Not InstalledDIMM 4D Not InstalledDIMM 5A ( DDR2-FBD )    2048 Mbytes (667 MHz)DIMM 6B ( DDR2-FBD )    2048 Mbytes (667 MHz)DIMM 7C Not InstalledDIMM 8D Not InstalledECC memory installed    YesHardware PAE enabled    No
```

почему написано Hardware PAE enabled    No, если в boot прописано pae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В HP об этом глюке знают и говорят, что если память доступна а диагностика говорит что PAE отключен, то и фиг с ним. Читайте [тут](http://g2w1140.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&prodSeriesId=460016&prodTypeId=18964&objectID=c01857979)

Comment: спс понял)